# Word for the sky as seen from a spaceship not in orbit

Tags: single-word-requests

Since the word sky indicates "[the region of the atmosphere and outer space **seen from the earth**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sky)," what word would best be used by an astronaut on a spaceship no longer orbiting the Earth to describe what the astronauts saw looking out a window. Example-when the Apollo astronauts were traveling to and from the Moon.

Comment: "... to describe what is seen above the horizon." The horizon of what, earth or the moon?

Comment: You are taking that definition too literally. There are other dictionaries...

Comment: https://earthsky.org/space/how-often-can-you-see-sunrises-and-sunsets-from-the-moon uses the term “lunar sky”, in which the earth is always in the same place

Comment: The OED has the following as its first sense of the word "sky". *The region of the atmosphere and outer space seen from the earth in which the sun, moon, stars, and clouds appear, (esp. in early use) regarded as having the appearance of a vast vault or canopy. Cf. firmament n. 1a. Also occasionally in figurative contexts*. So @Xanne is undoubtedly right that the answer would be *lunar sky* - and should post the comment as an answer.

Comment: @Xanne Lunar sky makes sense based on my original question.  I reworded the question.

Comment: I think this question boils down to asking what astronauts call the image of all that stuff out there. Not 'outer space', but the -image- of all that to you.

Comment: How about 'the celestial sphere'? Works from on Earth and also off the Earth.

Comment: @Mitch  It communicates the idea, but I always thought that phrase sounded grandiose and makes me think of ancient cultures.  I'm hoping for a word that might be heard in casual conversation, or at least has a contemporary feel to it.

Comment: @Bob516 It feels very technical to me, but yeah I can see it being a bit too much. 'Sky' definitely seems weird with no ground below you. Maybe over at Space Exploration.SE they would know better.